# ec2 cloudformation template without default vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The EC2 template  is a basic template but it fails because the default vpc no longer exist. As a result it errors, Usually ill set it up under Paremeters, Default value.

creating a default VPC is unfortunately not an option....

How can this be modified to use a particular VPC?

only after figuring out what the errors really mean I have learned that I  have to assign the VPC and can't tell it to use the 'default'

```
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Description: Testing using  VPC created
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-8787789
  Subnet:
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-7657657578



...
...
...
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref 'InstanceSecurityGroup'
      KeyName: !Ref 'KeyName'
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - AWSRegionArch2AMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - HVM64
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref 'SSHLocation'
```

I guess what I am trying to understand is how I modify this code to use a specific vpcid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is most probably coming from `InstanceSecurityGroup` because it is not specifying a value for `VpcId`. Therefore, it is defaulting to the Default VPC, which does not exist. To fix this, add: `VpcId: VPC`

```
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref 'SSHLocation'
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

Comment: Hi.. so I had it that way. I had the !ref vpc as you mentioned and  in the parameters section  the default vpc and the actual VpcID was placed there. . But when I run it all I get is a roll back stating “ no default vpc”. As I mentioned we do not have a default vpc any longer and unfortunately I can not recreate it so this is where I am stuck..

Comment: Ah! The error is coming from `InstanceSecurityGroup`. See my update above.

Comment: Let me post exactly what I put because I thought I did that but clearly u know exactly what I am messing up on.. I do appreciate the help.. I’m trying to learn this and I won’t lie... it is not easy

Comment: ok.. are you saying place:   VpcId: vpc-877866 in the location  I actually put  VpcId: !Ref VPC.  This is what I messed up on?  I am attempting to reference a 'default' vpc that does not exist...

Comment: Updated with example.

Comment: So the reference of the vpc has to be in the location of the “InstanceSecueityGroip”. Do you see any other gotchas that I have not  hit.. subnets..etc.. I appreciate your help..

Comment: Well, the EC2 instance will launch in a random subnet. That's fine, but you can specify it if you wish, by providing a `SubnetId` instead of a `VpcId`.

Comment: I have taken your advice and that did fix one issue, but I now have the error below. I had to use the SubnetId instead of VpcId in the EC2 part because it errored saying VpcId is not supported. I did also place the VpcId  in the Security Group area.so that issue is gone. I am now stuck with this issue.

Comment: ` The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: be3b5cc4-d685-41c4-989e- `

Comment: OK.. I got it. I had to change SecurityGroups SecurityGroupIds and it worked to completion.. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a subnet id to the EC2 config, VpcID to the security group and you should be able to create EC2 and linked security group with a non default VPC

```
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref EC2SubnetID
    ...
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Vpcid: !Ref VpcId
    ...
```